# One to Many Relationship Searching for invalid id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on a school project and i'm new to ROR. I have two objects, Receipts and Subjects. The receipts have one subject and the subjects are reused among the receipts. I don't have a problem if I have equal number of subjects to receipts, but when I don't create a new subject for a receipt I get this error:[Screenshot of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GlVe.png)
The problem here is I only have two subjects in the database with 3 receipts. So an id of 3 for subject is invalid. My models, views, controllers, and migrations are follow.

```
class Receipt < ActiveRecord::Base 
belongs_to :user
has_one :subject, :foreign_key => :id
validates :user_id, presence:true
validates :descript, presence: true, length: { minimum: 4, maximum: 120      }
end

class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :receipts
validates :subject_name, presence: true, length: { minimum: 2, maximum: 30 }
validates :description, presence: true, length: { minimum: 2, maximum: 200 }
end


The View: 
<% @receipts.each do |receipt| %>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><%= receipt.date %></td>
            <td><%= receipt.subject.subject_name %></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <% end %>

 class ReceiptsController < ApplicationController 
    def index
    @receipts = Receipt.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 4).order("updated_at DESC")
    end
    end


class CreateReceipts < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
create_table :receipts do |t|

  t.datetime :date
  t.decimal :tax_amount, :purchase_amount, precision: 5, scale: 2
  t.boolean :approved, default: false
  t.text :descript
  t.integer :user_id, :subject_id
  t.timestamps
end
end
end


class CreateSubjects < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
create_table :subjects do |t|
t.string :subject_name
t.text :description
t.timestamps
end
end
end
```

I think my migration and views are fine since it works when I have equal subjects to receipts, but would really appreciate any feed back at this point.  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your association. A `has_one` association tries to look into the association table, `Subject` in this case, a record with `foreign_key` equals to the `id` of the object that has the association `Receipt`, in this case 3.

You could either get rid of `has_one :subject` and instead use a method like

```
def subject
  Subject.find_by_id subject_id
end
```

Or you can change the association to `belongs_to :subject`.

You shouldn't have `has_one` or `has_many` in both sides of the association. Since you have the `has_many` in the `Subject` you should use `belongs_to` in `Receipt`.

Hope that helps.